# Split video into multiple parts - in one go

Tags: video, gui

I have quite a lot of videos (with sign language sentences), that I want to split into multiple parts (one sentence in each part) simplify playback.

I know there are several video editing program where **I can select one clip, export that, then select the next clip and export that etc**..., but I'm looking for an easier way to **export multiple clips in one go**.

I would like to have an approach similar to that of splitting a sound file in Audacity (where I simply add a label track and add a label for each cut, and then use "File > Export Multipe…" to export all the clips an once).

How would I achieve this? (And what program should I use?)

**EDIT:** This is different from many other how-to-split-a-video-into parts questions, in that I want a quick easy way to split one large video file into multiple smaller parts and keeping all the frames of the original (e.g. the extracted parts should, if concatenated together again should contain all the frames of the original video).

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool where things are close to what you describe:

[dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.fr/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html), where you

1. select type of action: Split
2. add media
3. select type of split: multiple cuts
4. set cut point
5. add cut point
6. run

[image]

It is a ffmpeg GUI, shows a terminal while working,  outputs as mkv, but it is just splitting and copying I guess, as the time it takes is about the same of copy/pasting the initial full file.

The author of the tool is on askubuntu: [mdalacu](https://askubuntu.com/users/122038/mdalacu).

Comment: To bad we can't download it as a snap or from the software center.  Looks like they have been taken off.  And I don't recommend installing a deb file from an non-trusted google drive account.